# How to get all posts of a Facebook's user Newsfeed?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

This return all of my post

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message, likes FROM stream WHERE source_id = me()
```

but I'd want to get all posts a user sees on its Newsfeed. Is that possible?

I've tried this:

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message, likes FROM stream
```

but I get

> {   "error": {
>
> ```
> "message": "(#601) Parser error: unexpected end of query.", 
> "type": "OAuthException", 
> "code": 601   } }
> ```

Comment: FQL queries need a WHERE clause. You could use the news feed stream filter, `… WHERE filter_key = 'nf'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FQL queries need a WHERE clause.

You could use the news feed [stream filter](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream_filter): `… WHERE filter_key = 'nf'`